# What is the expected number of subarrays of size 0, 1 and 2 when quicksort is used to sort an array of N items with distinct keys?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, probability, quicksort

I am reading Robert Sedgewick's book *Algorithms 4th edition*, and he has the following exercise question: *What is the expected number of subarrays of size 0, 1 and 2 when quicksort is used to sort an array of N items with distinct keys?*

Then he says that if you're mathematically inclined, do the math, if not, run experiments, I have run the experiments and it seems like the arrays of size 0 and 1 have precisely the same number of occurrences and the arrays of size 2 are only half as occurrent.

**The version of quicksort in question is the one with 2 way partitioning.**

I understand that we get subarrays of size 0 when the partitioning item is the smallest/biggest one in the subarray, so the consequent 2 calls for the sort will be

```c#
sort(a, lo, j-1); // here if j-1 < lo, we have an array of size 0
sort(a, j+1, hi); // here if j+1 > hi, we have an array of size 0
```

The arrays of size 1 happen when the partitioning item is 2nd to first smallest/biggest item, and of size 2 when it's 3rd to first smallest/biggest item.

So, *how exactly do I derive a mathematical formula?*

Here is the code in C#

```c#
class QuickSort
{
    private static int zero = 0, one = 0, two = 0;
    private static int Partition<T>(T[] a, int lo, int hi) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        T v = a[lo];
        int i = lo, j = hi + 1;
        while(true)
        {
            while(Alg.Less(a[++i], v)) if(i == hi) break;
            while(Alg.Less(v, a[--j])) if(j == lo) break;
            if(i >= j) break;
            Alg.Swap(ref a[i], ref a[j]);
        }
        Alg.Swap(ref a[lo], ref a[j]);
        return j;
    }
    private static void Sort<T>(T[] a, int lo, int hi) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if(hi < lo) zero++;
        if(hi == lo) one++;
        if(hi - lo == 1) two++;

        if(hi <= lo) return;
        int j = Partition(a, lo, hi);

        Sort(a, lo, j - 1);
        Sort(a, j + 1, hi);
    }
    public static void Sort<T>(T[] a) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        Alg.Shuffle(a);
        int N = a.Length;
        Sort(a, 0, N - 1);
        Console.WriteLine("zero = {0}, one = {1}, two = {2}", zero, one, two);
    }
}
```

**There's a proof that says that on average quicksort uses 2NlnN ~ 1.39NlgN compares to sort an array of length N with distinct keys.**

**I guess we can think of 1.39NlgN as we do N comparisons ~lgN times, so on average we divide our array in half, hence at some point we will be left with pairs to compare, and since there are only pairs to compare, for example : <1,2>,<3,4>,<5,6>,etc..., we will get subarrays of size 0 and 1 after partitioning them, that only proves that sizes of 0 and 1, are more frequent, but I still don't understand why sizes of 2 are almost exactly half as frequent.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QuickSort will recursively partition the array into two smaller array at position k. k can be from 1 to n. Each k has the same probability of occurrence. Let `C0(n)` be the average number of appearances of 0-sized subsets, and `C1(n)`, `C2(n)` be the same for 1-sized and 2-sized subsets.

Apart from initial conditions, each satisfies:

```
C(n) = 1/n sum(C(k-1) + C(n-k) for k=1..n)
```

The two parts of the sum are the same but summed in the opposite order, so:

```
C(n) = 2/n sum(C(k-1) for k=1..n)
```

or

```
n*C(n) = 2*sum(C(k-1) for k=1..n)
```

Assuming neither `n` nor `n-1` are part of the initial conditions, we can simplify by subtracting `(n-1)C(n-1)` from both sides:

```
n*C(n) - (n-1)C(n-1) = 2*C(n-1)
```

or

```
C(n) = (n+1)/n * C(n-1)
```

**Deriving results from the recurrence relation**

We now have a recurrence relation `C(n)` which applies equally to `C0`, `C1` and `C2`.

For `C0`, we have initial conditions `C0(0)=1`, `C0(1)=0`. We compute `C0(2)` to get `1`, and then we can apply the simplified recurrence relation `C0(n) = (n+1)/n * C0(n-1)` for n>2 to get the general result `C0(n)=(n+1)/3`.

For `C1`, we have initial conditions `C1(0)=0`, `C1(1)=1`. As before, we compute `C1(2)` to get `1`, and apply the same procedure as for `C0` to get the general result `C1(n)=(n+1)/3`.

For `C2`, we have initial conditions `C2(0)=C2(1)=0`, and `C2(2)=1`. This time we compute `C2(3) = 1/3 * 2 * (C2(0) + C2(1) + C2(2)) = 2/3`. Then applying the simplified recurrence relation to infer the general result `C2(n)=(n+1)/4 * C2(3) = (n+1)/4 * 2/3 = (n+1)/6`.

**Conclusion**

We've shown the average number of appearances of 0-sized and 1-sized subarrays when quicksorting an array of size n is in both cases (n+1)/3. For 2-sized subarrays we've shown it's (n+1)/6.

This confirms your original observation that 2-sized subsets appear exactly half as often as 0 and 1-sized subsets, and gives an exact formula for the means.

Comment: That equation is termed "recurrence relation", and what exactly does it mean in your case?

Comment: @paulpaul1076, in QuickSort, you will recursively partition the array into two smaller array. k is position which QuickSort will split. But we don't kow where the k is, but we know that k can be from 1 to n and each case has a same probability.

Comment: I understand that we reduce the subarray size by 1 each time, so n becomes smaller..But I still don't understand the entire thing

Comment: Looks correct to me, but how about subarrays of size 0? When C_0=1, you get (N+1) average occurrence, but that over-counts since each subarray of size 1 you encounter will count as producing 2 subarrays of size 0 (rather than none). But (N+1) - 2*(N+1)/2 = 0, which isn't right...

Comment: Yeah, it is (N+1) for subarray of size 0. The reason that your count function does not count N+1 because that when you are C_1, you prevent C_0 from executing. In my equation, it does not prevent C_1 from going to C_0

Comment: @invisal I think you should be able to correct the zero-subset size by subtracting twice the number of 1-subsets you expect. But that gives 0. What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: @Anonymous, it should be zero-subset subtracting the number of 1-subset that we expect. Because, based on equation, C_1 = C_0 + 0 (+ 0 because we don't count the C_1 occurrence).

Comment: @invisal I don't see why it's right to subtract once rather than twice, but I still like your answer ;)

Comment: @Anonymous, yeah, sorry. My mind was gone wild because I was thinking too hard. I guess my math is still bad :(

Comment: I have figured out the mistake. For subarrays of size 2, you don't have nC(3)=(n+1)C(2) since C(2) is fixed and not 2*(C(0)+C(1))/2. Instead C(3) = 2/3 by calculation, and you get C(n) = (n+1)/6 for n>2. For subarrays of size 0 and size 1, C(2)=1 and C(n)=(n+1)/3 for n>2.

Comment: @Anonymous, Yeah, you are right. You are genius. You may edit my post.

Comment: I understand how you derived everything but can't understand how you get (N+1)/3 for C1 etc. Also, usually in recurrence relations there should be a base case, which is C0, I guess, and I don't understand what that is equal to, especially due to the fact that that's the thing that we need to find.

Comment: @invisal I heavily edited your proof, removing the images, fixed the bug, and tried to explain how C relates to the number of 0, 1 and 2-sized subsets. I hope you don't mind the changes ;/

Comment: now i finally understand, since you write CY(X), makes more sense

Comment: @Anonymous also you keep saying *we compute C0(2) and C1(2) to get 1*, if C0(1) = 0 how do we get C0(2) = 1? from the formula we have that C0(2) = (2+1)/2 * C0(1) = 3/2 * 0 and that gives us 0. Same for C1(2), C1(2) = 3/2 * 1 = 3/2, how did you get 1?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 The simplified formula isn't guaranteed to hold when n or n-1 is one of the initial conditions cases. The step where we subtract (n-1)C(n-1) is wrong if C(n-1) isn't 2*sum(C(k-1) for k=1..n-1).

Comment: @Anonymous, let's look at C0(2) for example, say, we have an array { 1,2 }, if the first item is the partitioning one, we get one 0 element array, if the second item is the partitioning one we also get one 0 element array. so altogether we have 2/2 = 1, same for C1(2), but how did you get (n+1)/3? for n > 2?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 repeatedly apply the simplified formula until you get down to n=2. The fractions (n+1)/n almost all cancel out.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside the mathematics, one thing is totally clear: when quicksort is called with a two-element partition, it will then issue two recursive calls, one of which has a zero-element partition and the other of which has a one-element partition.

So there will certainly be one one-element partition and one zero-element partition counted for every two-element partition counted.

In addition, one- and zero-element partitions can occur spontaneously, without a two-element parent, when the selected partition element is either the largest/smallest or second-largest/smallest element in the current partition. Roughly speaking, these should be about as likely as each other, and also as likely as that a two-element partition shows up.

So the observed results are not unexpected.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was thinking about pairs, and totally forgot that for every 2 element subarray, we'll have about twice as much of 1 element and 0 element subarrays, hm, I still don't understand how to prove it mathematically though, but good point.

Comment: I think this _is_ a proof that the number of 1 and 0 element subsets are the same as each other and that the number of 2 element subsets is double that.

Comment: @Anonymous, actually this is a proof that 0 and 1 element subarrays happen at least as many times as 2 element subarrays, there's nothing about doubling. If we have 2 two-element subarrays , we'll get 2 one- element and 2 zero-element subarrays after partitioning

Comment: @paulpaul1076: Suppose you have a partition of size k > 5. I suggest that the *immediate* partitions of size 0, 1 and 2 are equally likely, because the partitioning element is distributed uniformly over the possible partition points. So the number of *final* partitions of size 0 and 1 will be double, because each partition of size 2 *also* generates one each of a partition of size 0 and size 1.  This is not a proof; just an intuition. It lacks analysis of k=3,4,5 and the distribution might not be uniform if there are many repeated values.

Comment: @rici 3, 4, 5 works fine and there are no repeated values by assumption. You can formalize your intuition it by proving the claim by induction, which will use the fact that even deep in the recursion stack every permutation of the current sub-array is equally likely (which I know because Sedgewick is careful in how he specifies quicksort to make this true).

Comment: @anonymous: ah, right, "with distinct keys". I missed that the second time around.